# Trying to scrape a table using Scrapy

Tags: python, html, css, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape the table on http://www.casemanagementguidebook.ie/Case-Management-Listings/Accommodation---Homelessness.aspx so that I can enter all the values into MySQL database. When trying to do it in a shell I have tried the commands

```
table = response.css('table.listing-table')[0]
```

which has given me a table value showing

```
table = Selector xpath=u"descendant-or-self::table[@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' listing-table ')]" data=u'<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" b'
```

How do I access that data? I have tried using the command

```
 access = table.css("data").extract()
```

and also tried

```
access = table.css("tbody tr td").extract()
```

Both of which have returned an empty set. What path or command am I missing to access the td's within the table?

Answer (score 3):

So what you are looking for is the `<td>` element in each table row `<tr>`.

In order to do that you will

1. Need to first select all table rows
2. Iterate through each table row and find the `<td>` elements for each of them.

Like this:

```
trs = response.css('.listing-table tr')
for tr in trs:
    tds = tr.css('td')
    for td in tds:
        print td.extract()
```